Why is there no ssizeof operator in C++?
std::ssize was added in C++20 for the following reasons. Surely if it is justifiable to have std::ssize then it is equally justifiable to have ssizeof for the same reasons. Is it just a case of nobody has bothered to propose it, or is there some good reason for its absence?

ssizeof would be a new language keyword, and adding a new keyword is much harder than adding a new namespace-qualified name.

What do you think sizeof does?  And based on that, what would ssizeof do?

@StephenNewell I know what sizeof does. As for ssizeof, is it not obvious enough? What do you think it would do?

When a keyword is added to the language there will always be a risk that someone already has a variable with the same name, thus breaking existing code (which is a kind of a no-go area). Just adding it as a function in the std:: namespace should not break any existing code (unless someone was stupid enough to add functions to the std namespace in their code). Also ssizeof would only be able to work on built-in-types, which ranges are not.

@PepijnKramer I don't know if I'd call it a no-go area. Since C++11 they have added many new keywords. alignas, alignof, auto, concept, decltype, noexcept, nullptr... just to name a few.

"Why is there no ssizeof operator in C++?..." I would also recommend adding what you think ssizeof should mean in your post, however obvious you may think it is. C++ is a complicated language, and many obvious looking things are not obvious at all. And sizeof always return greater than 0, so it is even more important to know what you think ssizeof should do and why is there a need for ssizeof. Just because there is std::ssize, isn't a reason.

I'm asking what you think ssizeof should do since I can't think of any scenario where it could return a negative number, assuming it matches behavior with sizeof.  sizeof works at compile-time, so presumably ssizeof would as well?

@StephenNewell "I can't think of any scenario where it could return a negative number" Can you think of a scenario where std::size or vector::size would return a negative number? I assume you didn't read P1227. ssizeof would be the same as sizeof but would return a type which is not unsigned. In my case, I had a series of auto type deduced variables, one of which included a sizeof operator, which causes the expression to become unsigned, along with any auto type deduced expression that included that variable.

It ultimately led to a scenario where the result of an expression which was assumed to be a signed type was being checked if it's greater than zero, and this check did nothing because the value had blown up to a very large number. I think it would be great if signed types were the default in C++, but that shipped has sailed. But if std::ssize can be added, then I don't see why ssizeof could not be added as well.

Your question is weak because it does not summarize the reasons. Questions should be understandable on their own, even when an external link is provided for additional context.

On SO where answers are supposed to be objective and not opinion-based, it's monumentally difficult to answer why something was done in a language, and it's downright impossible to answer why something wasn't done. The only way you can get an answer is to read the minds of a few million developers and find out why they never decided to propose such a thing.

@Chris_F Fair enough, they did do that indeed.

@PasserBy Well for C++ there are always the committee meeting notes and proposal papers. Thing is they are not always an easy read ;)

If there was a ssizeof operator, it either would produce the same result as an expression using sizeof (e.g. for an array, it might have the same effect as std::ptrdiff_t (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])) or it would be a diagnosable error (e.g. if its operand was a pointer).    Adding new language keywords tends to only be done to achieve something that cannot readily be done with the existing language.   Whereas, the hurdle for new facilities of the standard library (as is the case for std::ssize()) is not as high.

The reference listed for the rationale talks to the potential of the result of a small subtraction on size wrapping round when the container size is 0. sizeof doesn’t result in a zero size. CPP reference;

The result of sizeof is always nonzero, even if applied to an empty class type.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof
The ssize is intended for use on containers with elements, sizeof is intended for use on objects and types, their targets are different, the rationale runs a little different as well.
That all said, if your use case requires it, it wouldn’t be too difficult to get something implemented for it in a similar fashion.

"Can we declare an object of a class inside a function of the same class in C++?..." It(sizeof) can also be applied to "types" as well. In the sizeof, it also mentions the same: "Queries size of the object or type. "
